# Find if value has moved quickly in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in with a variable, value (which begins with NAs) and time at which that value is valid. I want to determine if the value has changed quickly recently, where moving 'quickly' is defined as decreasing/increasing by more than 5 in the past minute

For example, here is my dataframe

```
example <- data.frame(variable = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                      time = c(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 5, Sys.time() + 15, Sys.time() + 34, Sys.time() + 151, Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 1, Sys.time() + 5, Sys.time() + 77, Sys.time() + 79, Sys.time() + 102, Sys.time() + 110, Sys.time() + 145),
                      value = c(NA, 3, 6, 2, 8, NA, 15, 11, 8, 6, 4, 0, 3))
```

You can visualise the data using the code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(example, aes(x = time, y = value, by = variable)) + geom_step()
```

I want to add a boolean column showing whether the value has moved by more than 5 in the past minute, so would end up with the following:

```
   variable                time value fast_move
1         a 2017-11-06 15:59:10    NA     FALSE
2         a 2017-11-06 15:59:15     3     FALSE
3         a 2017-11-06 15:59:25     6     FALSE
4         a 2017-11-06 15:59:44     2     FALSE
5         a 2017-11-06 16:01:41     8      TRUE
6         b 2017-11-06 15:59:10    NA     FALSE
7         b 2017-11-06 15:59:11    15     FALSE
8         b 2017-11-06 15:59:15    11     FALSE
9         b 2017-11-06 16:00:27     8     FALSE
10        b 2017-11-06 16:00:29     6     FALSE
11        b 2017-11-06 16:00:52     4      TRUE
12        b 2017-11-06 16:01:00     0      TRUE
13        b 2017-11-06 16:01:35     3     FALSE
```

Row 5 is `TRUE` as it has gone from 2 to 8 (a change of 6) in one go.

Row 9 is `FALSE` because although it has moved from 15 to 8, it did this in over 60 seconds

Row 11 is `TRUE` because it has gone from 11 to 4 in 26 seconds (was 11 at 16:00:26 and 4 at 16:00:52). Similarly row 12 is `TRUE`

The actual dataframe is over 1,000,000 rows with lots of variables, so anything which is particularly slow may be problematic!

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

To answer useR's comment about what I have done so far...

- I have currently found what the value was 60 seconds previously, and calculated the difference. If this is > 5 set fast_move as TRUE. Used the following code to do this

  ```
  isFastMove <- function(data){

  library(data.table)

  data <- data %>% 
      unique() %>% 
      data.table

  prevData <- mutate(data, time = time - 60) %>% 
      select(-value) %>% 
      data.table

  setkeyv(data, c('variable', 'time'))
  setkeyv(prevData, c('variable', 'time')) 

  prevData <- data[prevData, roll = T, rollends = T] %>% 
      mutate(time = time + 60) %>% 
      rename(previous_value = value)

  data <- merge(data, prevData, by = c('variable', 'time')) %>%     
      mutate(fast_move = !is.na(previous_value) & abs(value - previous_value) > 5)

  return(data)
  }
  ```

However this doesn't always work, for example if the value was 3, then dropped to 1 and immediately increased to 7. This would be a fast move but when I compare to 30 seconds ago it was 3, and wouldn't be classed as a fast move.

Comment: At the moment I have found what the value was 60 seconds previously, and calculated the differerence. If this is > 5 set fast_move as TRUE. However this doesn't always work, for example if the value was 3, then dropped to 1 and immediately increased to 7. This would be a fast move but when I compare to 30 seconds ago it was 3, and wouldn't be classed as a fast move

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far and explain why it doesn't give you the expected output in your question? Don't post this as a comment

Comment: Just to clarify, I have a question about two scenarios: (1) `value` moves from 3 to 6 to 9 within 45 seconds; should `fast_move` be `TRUE` or `FALSE` when `value` is 9? (2) `value` moves from 3 to 11 to 7 within 45 seconds; should `fast_move` be `TRUE` or `FALSE` when `value` is 11?

Comment: For row 5, the difference is only 5 and the time is greater than 1 min, why TRUE??? Your description is not matching your example for row 11 as well..

Comment: @duckmayr Both should be TRUE

Comment: @F.Privé For row 5 it is TRUE because at 16:01:40 the value is 2, and at 16:01:41 the value is 8. A movement of 6 in one go. For row 11 the value is 4 at 16:00:52 but was 11 at 16:00:26 (just before it changed to 8 at 16:00:27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this **Rcpp** function for one variable should be fast:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector fastMove(const NumericVector& time,
                       const NumericVector& value,
                       double nsec = 60,
                       double nval = 5) {

  int n = time.size();
  LogicalVector fast_move(n);

  int i, j;
  double tmin, vmin, vmax;

  for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    tmin = time[i] - nsec;
    vmin = value[i] - nval;
    vmax = value[i] + nval;
    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
      if (time[j + 1] - 1 < tmin) break;
      if (value[j] < vmin || value[j] > vmax) {
        fast_move[i] = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return fast_move;
}
```

To apply this function to each variable, use **dplyr**:

```
library(dplyr)
example %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(fast_move = fastMove(time, value))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is close but doesn't quite work. It assumes that the value is only valid at that one specific time, whereas in reality the value is valid until the next change. I will use row 5 as an example

We have value 2 in row 4 at 15:59:44 and value 8 in row 5 at 16:01:41. The above compares those times and assumes it took 117 seconds to change. However, in actual fact it was value 2 all the way from 15:59:44 to 16:01:40 so the increase of 6 actually happened immediately and so should be classed as a fast move

Comment: Managed to get it how I wanted by editing the first line of the `j` for loop to `if (time[j + 1] - 1 < tmin) break;`. Will edit the above answer